# Codeigniter extending exception class

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to load a custom exception class that I created according to the instructions here:

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html

`MY_Exceptions.php` is stored at `application/core/`

Somehow, when I try loading it, I keep getting this error:

> Fatal error: Class 'MY_Exceptions' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\facebook\application\models\campaign_model.php on line 29

Based on the instructions, it doesn't say I have to autoload the class or anything.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> MY_Exception.php is stored at application/core/

Name the class and file `MY_Exceptions` with an **s**

You do not need to autoload or manually load anything in the `core` directory, nor should you. They are required classes for CI to run that are automatically loaded.

For creating core classes, use this documentation instead: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html

Keep in mind that when calling the class you will use the original class name. Let's say you have created `MY_Input`. Example:

```
$this->input->post();  // Do this
$this->my_input->post(); // Don't do this
```

To understand the why and how, see `system/core/Common.php` function `load_class`.

Looking at the docs now, I agree that this should probably be highlighted.

Comment: sorry, that was a typo - i do have it named MY_Exceptions.php

Comment: You still don't need to load it, it's always loaded (and very early). Try just running CI without manually loading the class, you *should* be fine.

Comment: @Dhana: Are you sure you have followed the instructions correctly? The docs you are looking at are for non-core libraries.

Comment: Boy, today is definitely a typo day - I just realized I gave the wrong link too - I did follow the instructions on extending the core class

Comment: You're not trying to call the class manually are you? I've got to go back to work, GL.

Comment: wait a minute, so when a class gets extended, you don't really call the new class? but still call the old class?  Not really classic inheritance?

Answer (score 0):

It's trying to find MY_ExceptionS.php, not MY_Exception.php.

Comment: sorry, that was a typo - i do have it named MY_Exceptions.php